# Error in SQL query on server via phpmyadmin database import

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, webserver

I'm trying to import a database to my server via `phpMyAdmin` and I'm getting the following error and need some help to find the problem.

> ```
> SQL query:
>
> --
> -- Database: `mydata`
> --
> -- --------------------------------------------------------
> --
> -- Table structure for table `add_place`
> --
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `add_place` (
>
>  `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
>  `place_name` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
>  `place_tel` VARCHAR( 50 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
>  `place_email` VARCHAR( 250 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
>  `url` VARCHAR( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
>  `place_address` VARCHAR( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
>  `place_describe` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
>  `place_cat` VARCHAR( 150 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
>  `image` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
> PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
> ) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =21;
>
> MySQL said: 
>
> #1046 - No database selected
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Enter this command first:

```
use mydatabase;
```

(Obviously substitute "mydatabase" for whatever your database name is)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select your database that you are using.  `add_place` is your table and you would have to add `database_name.add_place` to ensure PHPMyAdmin can add this to the correct database.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create a database and then use `Import` from within it. In other words after you create a database you also need to click on its name on the left side of phpMyAdmin. Only after that you can use `Import` option because you are on the right "depth" in PMA. If you already have the database to which you want to import the data then simply click on it in the database list on the left side of PMA.

If you try to import your data directly through "Import" on the main page it will assume your SQL dump contains references to the database itself which is obviously not the case with your code.